# A Narration of a Prophet or Real Person marrying in the Quran (Part 1)

Tags: quran, nikah

Is there any case or narration in the Quran that tells about the marriage / the event of marrying of a Prophet or any Real (Existing / Existed) Person, **OTHER THAN** the one told in Al Ahzab 33:37?

I'm not asking about verses that tells about the RULES related to marriage.
I'm not asking about verses that tells the event of the birth of someone.
I'm asking only for verses that narrates about the event of Marriage of someone.

Post as many examples as you can with, of course, reference to the Surah(s) and Verse(s). Note also that I'm asking for Quranic references only.

This, I think, is supposed to be easy.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

The marriage of [Moses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses) (عليه السلام) is mentioned in [Quran 28:23-29](https://quran.com/28/23-29):

> #### قال إني أريد أن أنكحك إحدى ابنتي هاتين على أن تأجرني ثماني حجج فإن أتممت عشرا فمن عندك وما أريد أن أشق عليك ستجدني إن شاء الله من الصالحين
>
> He said, "Indeed, I wish to wed you one of these, my two daughters, on [the condition] that you serve me for eight years; but if you complete ten, it will be [as a favor] from you. And I do not wish to put you in difficulty. You will find me, if Allah wills, from among the righteous."
>
> #### قال ذلك بيني وبينك أيما الأجلين قضيت فلا عدوان عليّ واللّه على ما نقول وكيل
>
> [Moses] said, "That is [established] between me and you. Whichever of the two terms I complete - there is no injustice to me, and Allah, over what we say, is Witness."
>
> #### ... فلما قضى موسى الأجل وسار بأهله
>
> And when Moses had completed the term and was traveling with his family ...
>
> <sup>— [Quran 28:27-29](https://quran.com/28/27-30)</sup>

Comment: Just a question, Was the marriage done after the condition is met or before?

Comment: @Rextia there's also the story of the marriage of the Prophet pbuh with zaynab which might apply to some extent but you've mentioned it in your post already.

Comment: That's great. But I think I already mentioned that.

Comment: Is there any other example?

Comment: @Rextia, the marriage was done before the condition was met. Most scholars are of the belief that Mussa got married, spent the entire 10 years (the longer period) of service, then went back to Egypt. On his way back, he got his first revelation to go talk to the Pharaoh.

Comment: Ok. I agree This is indeed about the marriage of Prophet Musa. As per the OP question this is correct. But I want to ask does this talk about a "wedding event" just as in 33:37? Notice the slight difference. The "I wish to wed you one...." indicates that this verse is not narrating about the "wedding event" itself rather the condition for the marriage that was GOING to happen (at the time of the wedding itself, The Quran didn't narrate about it, unlike 33:37 CMIIW). Notice the difference. But it doesn't matter, as for the OP question, this is a valid answer. I just wanna highlight things here.

Comment: @III-AK-III  "Most scholars are of the belief that..." tells me that regarding when the wedding took place is still a topic debatable. Why? I think because regarding the "wedding event" itself is not narrated or mention in the Quran. It's just not there. This strengthen my argument in the comment above. CMIIW

Comment: @Rextia, "Most scholars are of the belief that Mussa got married, spent the entire 10 years (the longer period) of service" means most scholars say he spent 10 yrs. while the minority say he may have spent 8 yrs. There is no dispute about the time of the wedding.

Comment: @III-AK-III Does this verse actually narrates about the wedding event itself? or not?